# How can i preview custom code-based views in xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, swift

I create custom controllerView, but i want see without compilation. How can i preview results?

For example, my custom controller:

```
import Cocoa

class BreakWindowController: NSWindowController {

    let breakViewController = BreakViewController()
    var popoverManager: PopoverManager?

    // MARK: View lifecycle

    override func loadWindow() {
        self.window = BreakWindow(contentRect: self.breakViewController.view.frame, styleMask: NSBorderlessWindowMask, backing: NSBackingStoreType.Buffered, defer: false)
        self.window?.contentView = RoundedCornerView(frame: self.breakViewController.view.frame)
        self.window?.center()
        self.window?.animationBehavior = NSWindowAnimationBehavior.AlertPanel
        self.window?.display()
        self.window?.makeKeyWindow()
        self.window?.makeMainWindow()
        NSApp.activateIgnoringOtherApps(true)
        self.window?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(true)
        self.breakViewController.popoverManager = self.popoverManager
        self.popoverManager?.breakController = self

        (self.window?.contentView as! RoundedCornerView).visualEffectView.addSubview(self.breakViewController.view)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. This is the drawback of code based views. Think about it for a moment, without compilation, how could xCode know what the view looks like?

Answer (score 0):

What you are possibly looking for is the (relatively) new features in Interface Builder that allow you to create properties in a view that can be manipulated by controls in IB (NSInspectable) and that allows your custom view to be rendered in IB (NSDesignable).

Although it seems that links to Apple docs break whenever anyone sneezes, here are two links that should get you started: [Creating a Custom View that Renders in IB](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_objects_media/Chapters/CreatingaLiveViewofaCustomObject.html) and [Debugging a Custom View Without Running Your app](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_objects_media/Chapters/DebuggingCustomViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014224-CH42-SW1)

The main points in those documents are

1. If you decorate property declarations with `@IBInspectable` (or for Objective-C, `IBINSPECTABLE`) then control widgets for those properties appear in the attributes inspector in IB.
2. If you decorate your custom class with `@IBDesignable` (or for Objective-C, `IB_DESIGNABLE`), then (*essentially*) your `drawRect` method is run when the view is displayed in IB.

Here is Apple's example converted from Objective-C to Swift:

```
//
//  MyView.swift
//  ViewTest
//

import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class MyView: UIView {


  @IBInspectable var lineColor: UIColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
  @IBInspectable var lineWidth: CGFloat = 4.0

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect)
    {
      var context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
      let myFrame = self.bounds
      CGContextSetLineWidth(context, lineWidth)
      CGRectInset(myFrame, 5, 5)
      lineColor.set()
      UIRectFrame(myFrame)
    }

}
```

Below is what it looks like in IB. Note the two decorated properties, lineColor and lineWidth, and the controls in the attributes inspector.

[image]